# The best way to add/remove class to next element?

Tags: jquery

HTML

```
 <div class="item active" data-category="sharks">
 <div class="item" data-category="tigers">
 <div class="item" data-category="lions">

 <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" id="next-button" rel="nofollow">Next</a>

$("#next-button").click(".item:not(.active)", function (event) {
    $(".item.active", event.delegateTarget).removeClass("active");
    $(this).next().addClass("active");
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/X7L8q/)

I am trying to add `active` to the next `.item` class and remove `.item` from the previous.. easy I know.

also one more thing, how do I add `.active` when a specific data-id is clicked adding it to the matching data-category?

Basically two ways to add active to `.item` one from the next button, and then also from the navigation like thing you will see in the fiddle

Comment: I'm unclear on your "one more thing".

Comment: Similar to lumosity http://www.lumosity.com/app/v5/personalization/memory there is a breadcrumbs nav on the top, when you click one of the items it adds `.active` to the appropriate block... the block has a data-category the clickable button has a data-id.. what ever is clicked it adds `.active` to the matched category

Comment: Why does this get a -1??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you currently have will never work for a variety of reasons, chief amongst them:

1. None of your `.items` are children of `#next-button`.
2. Using `.click` does not delegate. In your example, `".item:not(.active)"` is data that is being passed to the handler.

If you are trying to make it so when someone clicks the `#next-button` the `active` class moves:

```
var items = $('div.item');
var currentItem = items.filter('.active');
$('#next-button').on('click', function() {
    var nextItem = currentItem.next();
    currentItem.removeClass('active');
    if ( nextItem.length ) {
        currentItem = nextItem.addClass('active');
    } else {
        // If you want it to loop around
        currentItem = items.first().addClass('active');
    }
});
```

If you want to click on the items and change:

```
var items = $('div.item').on('click', function() {
    var target = $(this);
    if ( ! target.hasClass('active') ) {
        $(this).addClass('active').siblings('.active').removeClass('active');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I didnt even know a .filter callback existed, I am going to study this code, I am sure I will have many uses for this in the future. It works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/X7L8q/2/)

```
$("#next-button").click(function (event) {
    $(".item.active").removeClass("active").next().addClass("active");
});
$(".breadcrumb-label").click(function (event) {
    $(".item.active").removeClass("active").siblings('[data-category="'+this.innerHTML+'"]').addClass("active");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$('#next-button').click(function(){
  var item = $('div.item.active');
  item.removeClass('active');
  item.next().addClass('active');
  if(item.next().length == 0){
    $('div.item').first().addClass('active');
  } 
})
```