# JQuery, How to Stop Loop and add Anchor to each element?

Tags: jquery, html, css

[This question was answered, but I cant stop the loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18065335/the-best-way-to-add-remove-class-to-next-element)

I am trying to create a simple slider that going from [1..4] slides, where the 4th slides hide `#next-button`. In same time it display a button on last slider. I tried to create it JQuery below, but I could not stop the loop. I tried to use .length == 3 to remove the class, but loop still continue working and effect other classes.

Question is there a way to create a simple .next() function that ends on 4th slide and hiding next button and show button an the end of the slide.

Also, is there a way to create a anchor for each slide, so on click it could change the class of the each item.

**JQuery**

```
var items = $('div.item');
var currentItem = items.filter('.active');
  $('#next-button').on('click', function() {
     var nextItem = currentItem.next();
     currentItem.removeClass('active');
      if ( nextItem.length ) {
         currentItem = nextItem.addClass('active');
      } else {
      // If you want it to loop around
      currentItem = items.first().addClass('active');
      }
  });
```

**HTML**

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#item_1" class="active_link">go to first item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#item_2">go to second item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#item_3">go to third item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#item_4">go to fourth item</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="item active" id="item_1">My first item</div>
   <div class="item" id="item_2">My Second item</div>
   <div class="item" id="item_3">My Third item</div>
   <div class="item" id="item_4">My Fourth item</div>
</div>
<div id="next-button">Go Next</div>
<button type="submit" class="submit-it">Submit</button>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 300px;
    position: relative;
}
.item {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
}
.item.active {
    display: block;
    z-index: 2;
}
#next-button {
    z-index: 3;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
.active_link {
    background-color: red;
}
.menu {
    display: flex;
    width: 300px;
    justify-content: space-between;
    height: 40px;
}
.menu li {
    width: 30px;
}
.submit-it {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan my mistake, I make a change

Comment: Also, don't use `href="item_1"` if you have absolutely no plans to navigate anywhere.

Comment: Ahaa you mean `When we are on the last slide show the SUBMIT button (currently hidden)`

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I am trying to hide #next-button and display .submit-it button on 4th slide

Comment: I guess you want something like this https://jsfiddle.net/573aszos/ Your problem is don't know how to know if the last slideshow is shown. There are many many ways, using `.next()` on `next` is just one of those.